# Getting "SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method " error on IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript method to change the form action and submit afterwards.

```
$(document).on('click','#q7', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.forms[0].action = "questionnaireQ7AvenantsAction.do?method=rechercheQuestion&typeQ=q7&modeQ=display";
    document.forms[0].submit();
});
```

Above code is working fine in all the browsers Except IE. I am using IE 10.
I am getting error on this line:

```
document.forms[0].action = "questionnaireQ7AvenantsAction.do?method=rechercheQuestion&typeQ=q7&modeQ=display";`
```

The error is

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method

Any help would be appreciated as I have been stuck on this problem for the last 2 days.

Comment: Try jQuery. `$('form:first').attr('action', 'thatLongString').submit();`

Comment: Can you confirm that IE is running in standards mode, and not quirks mode or compatibility mode? (Quirks mode in particular is likely to break jQuery)

Comment: Yes It's running in standard mode.

Comment: @Tushar: Its working by by your meyhod.

Comment: @Tushar: I have already added my comment for below answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you're already using jQuery for the event handler, you can also use it to amend your form. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#q7', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('form:first').attr('action', 'questionnaireQ7AvenantsAction.do?method=rechercheQuestion&typeQ=q7&modeQ=display').submit();
});
```

Comment: to match the OP's code, you probably only want to apply it to the first form on the page rather than all forms. But yes, this is the correct answer, given that they're already using jQuery.

Comment: I am again getting the same error. Its working on other browsers but not on IE.

Comment: [You might want to edit the answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39269167/getting-script438-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-error-on-ie?noredirect=1#comment66114386_39269167)

Comment: Thanks @Tushar. I updated to `attr()`. No idea why `prop()` wouldn't work for this in IE